# Unable to connect to the remote server in node js?

Tags: java, c#, node.js, amazon-web-services, express

I am trying to integrated the third party Recharge API . I have given the url to them whenever message is  success or failure  they have to update the URL.

When i  check my AWS system it shows through postman it getting the correct msg.

But When the 3rd Party tried to hit my URL the below error messages show

Unable to connect to the remote server    A connection attempt failed  because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond?

All i want to know whose side problem whether myside(Server side) or 3rd Party(Client side)

And i need a solution also.

Comment: Without putting code no one will be able to help you, so whenever posting any question please be sure to put relevant code.

Answer (score 0):

check your Security Group rules .. make sure it's open to the 3rd party.